Changing RGB band raster into single band raster in ArcMap
I have a raster like in this image, this raster symbology only consist of RGB Composite, vector field and stretched.
How do I change the colors of this raster into a single color?
This raster was originally named as MASK_CLASSI from Sentinel-2 data.


You need to understand what the original raster is telling you. According to the Level-1C Mask page the raster MSK_CLASSI has 3 bands representing Opaque clouds, Cirrus Clouds and snow and ice areas.  ArcMap is interpreting the 3 bands as if the raster is an image.
If you want to collapse all 3 bands into a single binary band you can use the Make Raster Layer tool to separate out each band. The tool allows you to choose the band. Then add the raster layers together using the raster calculator. The final output will be an integer raster which you can symbolise as you desire.
